# Is there any difference between "win out" and "win through"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Could you tell me if there is any difference between the phrasal verb *win out* and *win through*. For example:

> The amount of work I had to do was overwhelming, but in the end I **won out**.
>
> The amount of work I had to do was overwhelming, but in the end I **won through**.

Comment: win through is not a phrasal verb. Win out is a phrasal verb.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know that I've ever heard the phrase "win through" although it [appears to be idiomatic in UK English](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/win-through).

"Pushed through" can convey perseverance and is the closest alternative I can think of at the moment.

Also, your tenses disagree. If you're speaking about a quantity of work done in the past, you would say that:

> The amount of work I had to do was overwhelming, but in the end I won out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I wanted to know if there is a nuance of difference between "win out" and "win through".